# Cloned disk from older MacBook not booting on new MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, startup, bootable-disk

I have an old MacBook (2-3 years old), it is running 10.9.

Last night I cloned the hard drive and tried to use it as a startup disk on my new MacBook Pro (June 2016, with 10.11 installed).

All I got was a no entry sign on startup. How can I make it boot?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Please read http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice and the other articles in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Mac will boot to an OS older than itself, with the exception of models released right on the cusp of a new major OS version.

The drivers for the newer model didn't yet exist.